# Monitor IIS Site Recompilations .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, iis-7, iis-6, webserver

I was wondering if anybody could tell me how to tell when IIS last recompiled? We have a fairly large website which recompiles from time to time if somebody pushes app_code files up etc. We also have minor issues with our webservers which cause IIS to reboot the app pool which again I believe forces a recompile. It would be beneficial to us to be able to tell when IIS last recompiled a given site.

Are there any performance counters etc that have this information?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow this post to analyze ETW trace, you will see when the last compilation occured. As a typical troubleshooting approach, you can use it to find out the cause, but don't leave it running for ever, as it can hurt performance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET Health Monitoring to notify you when the application pool restarts. Use [ETW trace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing.aspx) (see the other answer) to debug it further.

See [this post](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/7ea62799-d1cb-42ee-a1f2-e68b28dbe836/restart-aspnet-apps-programmatically-log-applicationend-events-and-use-web-management-logging.aspx) on how to setup healthMonitoring (it's at the end of the article) or the official documention on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx).